# Plotly long dropdown not working on mobile

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, plotly

I made a plotly graph with a dropdown filter in R, it works good on the laptop, but on mobile it doesn't select the options from the list, although it does show the list upon clicking; not-working app is here: http://datamarindo.baselinux.net/blog/posts/16-cultivos-otra-vez/

I discovered that reducing the number of options, so the dropdown fits into the figure region makes it work, this would do for less than 15 options, I already reduced them to 40 from a total of over 100; I can't find parameters to control the length of the displayed list in plotly, or other types of data selection, like spinners.

I guess it's a bug, so I'm looking for a workaround

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(htmlwidgets)

q = read.csv("https://gitlab.com/datamarindo/cultivos_veracruz/-/raw/master/cultivos.csv")

pq = q |>  plot_ly(x = ~anio, y = ~total_toneladas, color = ~nomddr, 
                   transforms = list(list(type = "filter", 
                                          target = ~nomcultivo,
                                          operation = "=",
                                          value = "Arroz palay"))) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), yaxis = list(title = "Ton"),
         updatemenus = list(
           list(type = "dropdown", 
                active=0,
                buttons = apply(as.data.frame(sort(unique(q$nomcultivo))), 1,
                                function(x) list(method = "restyle", 
                                                 args = list("transforms[0].value", x), label = x)))))
pq = add_paths(pq)
pq
```